# Dart Language return on void method

Tags: dart

i spend (again) some hours to find a strange behavior in a dart program.
I ask me about the reason of the following and if there is something to do at the compiler level.
The code is simply about setting and removing entries in a Map and to trace the remove action:

```
static void removeLock(String key) {
    Lock lock = _locks.remove(key);
    if (lock !=null) return
    print ( " uniqueId $key was not locked ");
  }
```

Map documentation says that remove returns the object if it was in the map before the remove.
As it is written, the code says all time the key was not in the map.
The raw bug is obvious : the developer has forgotten to put a semicolon after return :

```
if (lock !=null)  return ;
```

First question was: Why this was not detected by compiler?

My analysis is that Dart try to return *the result of the call of print*, which is void, so it's ok with the method's signature. QED.

Question two : is there some manner to prevent such a mistake ;
Why is it allowed to give a void function call to a return statement ?
Is it a real use case for that ?

Comment: It is recommended in general to always use curly brackets for all control structures. You can get the analyzer to detect missing brackets by activating the following Linter hint: https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/curly_braces_in_flow_control_structures.html

Comment: I also want to recommend in general to include the Linter hints from the package pedantic or extra_pedantic (I am personally using the last one). The advantage of using this hints are that they hints your code to be more structurally consistent and more readable.

Comment: Lots of things are recommended by different people, often even contradictory things. The Dart style guide does [allow omitting the braces](https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/style#do-use-curly-braces-for-all-flow-control-structures) if the entire control flow structures fits on a single line.

Answer (score 1):

The reason this was not detected by the compiler is that the program is *valid*.

As you deduce, returning the result of a `void` expression like `print(...)` is allowed in a `void` function. That's allowed *mainly* for historical reasons.

In Dart 1, type annotations did not affect language semantics (types were optional), so a function should work the same whether it had a return type of `void` or not. All you could get was warnings, and some run-time errors when running in "checked mode". Because of that, there was no rule against returning something from a `void` function, the only rule that applied was that you couldn't have both `return;` and `return e;` statements in the same function, and even that was just a warning.
So, you *could* write `return e;` in a `void` function, and all it would check (in checked mode only) was check that the value was `null`.

Because of that, a lot of code was written which returned the value of void expression, especially as `=>` functions like `void foo() => voidBody();`.

When moving to Dart 2, where the type system is now checked at compile-time, it was not considered viable to make too much existing code invalid, so Dart 2 still allows `return voidExpression();` in a `void` function.